# What is a Toy Model for the mathematician's practice? Definition and examples

Tags: soft-question, terminology, big-list

Wikipedia says [Toy model (physics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_model):

> "In physics, a toy model is a simplified set of objects and equations relating them so that they can nevertheless be used to understand a mechanism that is also useful in the full, non-simplified theory.
>
> - ***In "toy" mathematical models**, this is usually done by reducing the number of dimensions  or reducing the number of fields/variables or restricting them to a particular symmetric  form.*
> - **In "toy" physical descriptions**, an everyday example of an analogous mechanism is often used to illustrate an effect in order to make the phenomenon easier to visualize."

I'm not used to physics terminology: for example, if I remember good, a *Physical Model* (like the Standard Model) is not exatly the same as a *Mathematical Model* (from model theory)... and this is enough to make me suspicious about the meaning of the term "Toy Model" when used inside a mathematical framework.

> $\mathcal Q 1$ **The wiki page seems to talk about Toy model in Physics... so what is the exact definition of a *Mathematical Toy Model*?**

and.. since the best way to understand are the examples

> $\mathcal Q 2$  **I'm looking for a big list of Toy Models, why they are introduced and how they are used.**

---

About the closure votes:

- **unclear what you're asking** : The question is really clear. Definition and list of examples are asked.
- **Too broad**: "*There are either too many possible answers*" **this is obvious** since the Tag "**Big List**" is used (and is used with "soft question" tag)..."*, or good answers would be too long for this format.*" **obviously wrong**, as  Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's comment shows.

Comment: On MO, [What are examples of good toy models in mathematics?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1354/what-are-examples-of-good-toy-models-in-mathematics)

Comment: A toy model is just a simple case of whatever difficult problem you are studying. There is nothing else, really...

Comment: "unclear what you're asking..."
 My question is: "What is a Toy Model?".What is unclear?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez can you add some details? Just a little. I'm not sure to understand. For example, if I have a difficult theorem to prove for a large class of structures, for example, then using a subclass of structure with nicer properties/well-behaved that makes the proof easier can be seen as the use of a Toy model?
ps:I apologize for my bad english.

Comment: "Toy problem" is a term of art in applied mathematical sciences.  It means a simplified problem, from which one hopes to glean insight into tackling a "real world" problem.  IMHO it is disingenuous to argue that "Mathematical Toy Model" must have a rigorous definition, based on your unfamilarity with "physics terminology".  Possibly, if you are "suspicious about the meaning of the term... when used inside a mathematical framework", then asking about a specific instance of such use would be an acceptably narrowed Question.